# Указатели и динамическое распределение памяти С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, указатели

У меня проблема,помогите.
Нужно код переделать с использованием указателей.

Задание:

Динамически выделить память под N элементов вещественного типа float. Разработать алгоритм и программу обработки данных с использованием указателей. Переставить в обратном порядке элементы, расположенные до первого максимального элемента.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");

    int size_array;
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> size_array;

    float* array = new float[size_array];

    for (int i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << array[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    float _max_array_Element = array[0];
    int _maxIndex;

    for (int i = 1; i < size_array; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > _max_array_Element)
        {
            _max_array_Element = array[i];
            _maxIndex = i;
        }
    }

    reverse(&array[0], &array[_maxIndex]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size_array; i++)
    {
        if (i < _maxIndex)
        {
            cout << array[i] << "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << array[i] << "\t";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нечего не понял. У вас код и так "с использованием указателей".

Comment: А..то есть все правильно сделано ?

Comment: Вам виднее "норм" или не "норм". Я не знаю, какие именно требования вкладываются это в странное "с использованием указателей".

Comment: У меня было такое задание - Разработать алгоритм и программу обработки данных с использованием указателей

Comment: И вы разработали эту программу, но при этом как-то не заметили, что использовали указатели? Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Да,делал по примера, но так и не понял где тут указатели.
Вы не могли бы мне помочь и показать где тут указатели ?